# Suggested Edit audits: who gets audited?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

There is a user who has been foiling my suggested edit rejections, and I noticed they currently have 237 approvals with **0** rejections.  That struck me as a little odd, because I figured they would have at least rejected an audit or two.  Then again, maybe not.

So, being bored, I started going through their review history, and I can't find a single instance of a suggested edit audit, either passed or failed.

I figure this user would have to be a *prime* candidate for an audit, so:

- How does the system determine who gets audited and who doesn't?
- Is this particular instance a case of the user not being audited, or simply detecting and skipping all audits for some reason?

Comment: `How does the system determine who gets audited and who doesn't?` My guess is you won't get an answer for that and that it will remain "undisclosed".

Comment: @Servy - that was my gut feeling as well; hopefully this will at least help the algorithms being used to be refined

Comment: I am really interested in the second option though; perhaps there will need to be some mod tool to indicate an overly high percentage of skips on audit items (if such a thing doesn't already exist).

Comment: A couple of days ago there was a post mentioning 1 in 20 reviews.

Comment: One reason for skipping obvious audits is to save the prescious votes for something  better. I sometimes consider doing that, to earn an extra reject vote. :-)